# What happens with method after `end` like `end.compact`?

Tags: ruby

In this code,

```
working_days = open(ARGV[0].to_s,'r').each_line.map do |line|    
  do_something
end.compact
```

the `map` function returns an array `[1, nil, 3, nil]`. I appended `compact` to the keyword `end`. I want to know what is behind the scene. After I add `compact`, does the return array become:

- `[1]` → `[1,3]` or
- `[1]` → `[1, nil]` → `[1, nil, 3]` → `[1, nil, 3, nil]` → `[1, 3]`

How can I use `pry` to inspect every step?

Will `compact`  be sent with the `do end` block into map function ?

Comment: As for pry, check: http://yorickpeterse.com/articles/debugging-with-pry/ https://github.com/nixme/pry-debugger https://github.com/pry/pry-stack_explorer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you are thinking it in a complicated way. It is done as:

```
[1, nil, 3, nil] → [1, 3]
```

There are no intermediate steps that you can observe.

Comment: Does compact will be sent with the `do end` block into map function ?

Comment: No. `compact` applies to the result of `map` which uses `do` ... `end`. By the time `compact` is applied, `map` is all done.

Answer (score 2):

There's no magic here. Your code is identical to the following:

```
tmp = open(...).each_line.map do |line|
  do_something
end

working_days = tmp.compact
```

You've simply removed the middle step, assigning the return value of `map` to a temporary variable.

It's the difference between doing this...

```
a(b(c()))
```

and doing this:

```
tmp = c()
tmp = b(tmp)
tmp = a(tmp)
```

You're simply invoking a function on a return value directly, rather than using a second statement.